# Computation expressions for a Haskell programmer

Tags: haskell, f#, monads, computation-expression

I'm looking to learn F#, but one thing that's confusing to me is the computation expression (do-notation??) syntax and desugaring.

In haskell, you have a very simple Monad typeclass and rules for desugaring do-notation into bind and return. There's no magic involved in adding keywords; the only thing must match up are the types.

In F# there's a bunch of builders, and keywords, and complexity.

Is there a good explanation of how to map one concept to the other?

I basically want to know how I map

```
do
  x <- monadicComputation
  foo x
  someOtherMonadicComputation
  let y = somePureComputation x
  return $ bar y
```

to F#.

The only keywords in the haskell are do, (<-) and let.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't write generic monadic code in F#, instead you have to specify the monad you're working in by naming the builder associated with the expression. Your example code would look like:

```
let example = async {
    let! a = someAsyncComputation
    foo a
    do! someOtherAsyncComputation
    let y = somePureComputation a
    return (bar y)
}
```

for the `async` computation expression type. The 'bang' pattern (do!, let! etc.) is used when binding monadic values, while the regular keywords are used for non-monadic values.

`let!` corresponds to bind `(>>=)` while `let` corresponds to `let` in `do` notation. `return` corresponds to `return`, while `return!` is used to yield an existing monadic value. `do!` is similar to `(>>)` which executes a monadic value for its effects, while `do` is for non-monadic effects, which has no parallel in Haskell.

Comment: I think you meant to say that `do!` is similar to `(>>)`.

Comment: I wish I could accept all of these answers, but I'm going to take this one since it seems the community has voted it up the most

Answer (score 5):

If you come from the Haskell background than you might be interested in [an academic article](http://sdrv.ms/16y054f) that I wrote about F# computation expressions recently.

It links the computation expression syntax (which is quite flexible) to standard type classes that are used in Haskell. As already mentioned, F# does not easily let you write code generic over monad (it *can* be done, but it is not idiomatic), but on the other hand it lets you choose the most appropriate syntax and you can even get nice syntax for `MonadPlus` or for monad transformers.

In addition to the `async` monad that was mentioned by Lee, here is an example of `MonadPlus` (using the sequence expression - a list monad - as an example):

```
let duplicate list = seq { 
  for n in list do 
    yield n 
    yield n ∗ 10 }
```

Or a computation expression for parsers:

```
let rec zeroOrMore p = parse {
  return! oneOrMore p 
  return [] }
```

Comment: I found this answer too late and the link seems to be broken now. Could you update your answer with the correct link, please?

Answer (score 4):

The haskell do notation has only one special syntax i.e `<-` which is mapped to `bind` function, everything else inside do is just normal function application for which the result is the monad type, for example: `return`, `putStr` etc.

Similarly in F# you have `let!` to represent `bind` operation and `return` keyword syntactic sugar (not normal function call like in haskell but this keyword maps to the `Return` function that you define). Now there are many other *keywords* that your computation expressions can support (you can omit them easily if not required), they all are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx). These additional operations sort of give you the syntactic sugar to use F# keywords instead of normal functions that return the monadic value. You can see that all the keyword that you can overload in F# computation expressions have monadic return value.

So basically, you don't need to be worried about all these keywords, just think of them as normal monad returning functions (with a specific type signature that you can find in documentation) that you can call using F# keywords inside the computation expression syntax.